# Fixed first row under Bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a fixed header for my form, in combination with a Boostrap navbar.

However when I apply some css defintions found from the navbar on the row it does become fixed but the row gets a lot of margin, so it does not expand the whole area. I notice this is due to the position definition.

```
<div class="row" style="top: 50px; position:fixed;">
</div>
```

How can I define a proper fixed row that expands the whole width of the area?

Answer (score 0):

Add this Style: `style="top: 50px; position:fixed; height: 80px; width: 100%; border: 1px solid #ccc"`

Comment: the right margin of the row is placed outside the screen now

Comment: Try margin: 0!important;